# Opening external links inside the app

Tags: android, iframe, intel-xdk

I am a newbie to Intel XDK and want to accomplish a simple task of opening my responsive webite placed on a server inside my app. I want to preserve the app header and or fotter. can anybody help? i have wasted tremendous time on googling and experimenting things... I have used IFrame. everything looks ok emulator but when i install the app on device, the webpage specified in iframe popups and my app header/footer disappears.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try WebView.
Add a WebView to your activity layout and this is how you load a URL in your code:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

A more detailed tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply.. Actually i'm using Intel XDK and don;t use android webview...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Cordova inAppBrowser plugin.